# How to display One2many field's view in my custom view?

Tags: forms, view, tree, odoo, one2many

My ticket has many comments and I created a view for my comment and make a One2Many field in ticket model. But it is not displaying my desired view. Here is my model

```
    class Ticket(model.Model):
      _name = 'Tickets'
      comment_ids = fields.One2many('comments', 'comment_id')
```

Here my second model

```
class Comments(models.Model):
_name = 'comments'

comment = fields.Text(string="Comment")
comment_id = fields.Char(string='Comment Id')
```

Here is my Ticket's View:

```
<notebook>
    <page name="body" string="Body">
        <field name="comment_ids" />    
    </page>
</notebook>
```

Here is my Comment's Form View:

```
<form>
   <div class="form-group">
      <label name="comment">Comment:</label>
      <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" />
   </div>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Here is my Comment's Tree View:

```
<tree>
   <field name = 'comment_id'/>
   <field name = 'comment'/>
</tree>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your comment model **have more than one tree view or form view**, if you don't specify
witch view you want to display Odoo will compute the one with the highest priority:

so just specify the `id` of the `tree view` in your `one2many` field

```xml
<field name="comment_ids" context="{'tree_view_ref': 'your_app.tree_view_xml_id', 'form_view_ref': 'your_app.form_view_xml_id'}"/>
```

Or you can use embedded view:

```xml
<field name="comment_ids">
        <tree>
            <field name = 'comment_id'/>
            <field name = 'comment'/>
        </tree>
        <form>
           <div class="form-group">
              <label name="comment">Comment:</label>
              <textarea class="form-control" rows="5" />
           </div>
           <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </field>
```

**Note**: if you have only this two views this means that Odoo didn't load this views so check if the `XML` file is in the `manifest` file and make sure you `upgrade` your module.

Comment: Can I connect with you? where I can directly mail you or something else?